# Percentage height does not have any effect

Tags: css

I'm trying to animate an accordion-style list, but not matter what percentage I give to the child, it shows up completely (even at 0%). See [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/AtOgIzA/3/edit?html,css,output)--if you change the "0%" to "0" (or "0px"), it hides just fine, but at 0% (or 1%, or 50%, or 100%, etc.) the child is fully visible. The percentages only seem to work if you give the parent `<li>` an explicit pixel height (but that doesn't play very well with animating the expand of the child).

I can understand how percentage heights might behave funny when the parent height is not specified, but 0% should be 0px all the time. That's what I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the CSS specification:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property

if a child element has a percentage height, and the height of its containing block is not explicitly set, then the child elment's height computes to `auto`, not `0px`.

Note that if the child element in question is positioned absolute, other CSS rules come into play.

Comment: I see. When I gave the parent a percentage height, it still didn't work--only with an explicit pixel height. I'm guessing that's because the same issue applied to the parent? Its parent didn't have an explicit height, so its height calculated to auto?

Comment: That is correct.  In your example, if the parent element `.accordion` has a % height, then it looks to `body` for a reference height.  To see any effect, you need to set `html, body { height: 100%; } and then `.accordian` would fill the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

The height in percentage sets the height according to the height of the parent. If the parent height is not set, you need to specify the height of the parent.

documentation says

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing
>   block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
>   height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value
>   computes to auto. A percentage height on the root element is relative
>   to the initial containing block.

So 0% height goes to `height:auto;` in this case.

Comment: That doesn't answer why "height: 0%;" makes the element display as though it had a height.

Comment: its not taking the 0%. instead set to height:auto